# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to consume a web api that adds a user in a database, so I created this startup class:

```cs
    public static class Startup
    {
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        public static void ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            //add services
            services.AddHttpClient<IUserServices, ApiUserServices>(c => 
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://10.0.2.2:9129/api/");
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            });

            //add viewmodels
            services.AddTransient<SignUpPageViewModel>();

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
  

        public static T Resolve<T>() => serviceProvider.GetService<T>();

    }
```

But I got this exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider'

Comment: Where exactly this exception is thrown? Is it in your code or somewhere in the framework?

Comment: @GoodboY in the code exactly in this line:  public static T Resolve<T>() => serviceProvider.GetService<T>();

Comment: It seems like the method `Resolve` is called before the `serviceProvider` is initialized by your code.

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: Do you call this `Resolve` method somewhere in your code?

Comment: no I called it only in this class

Comment: 1) The call is not included in your code snapshot. So, It is not clear how you call it. 2) Are you sure that you call it after the `ConfigureServices` is called?

Comment: https://github.com/techwithpat/XamWebApiClient I followed this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [XamWebApiClient / App.xaml.cs](https://github.com/techwithpat/XamWebApiClient/blob/master/XamWebApiClient/XamWebApiClient/App.xaml.cs), see the constructor:

```cs
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Startup.ConfigureServices();   <-- Do you have this line?
          
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }
```

The line `Startup.ConfigureServices();` is called before setting `MainPage`.

That sets `serviceProvider`, so should fix the null exception.

EXPLANATION: "Resolve" gets called to find the implementation of any services needed by HTTPClient.

In your case, code elsewhere probably refers to `IUserServices`?

`ConfigureServices` must be called before that code tries to use `IUserServices`.

---

IMPORTANT: If you have OTHER services that are used, but not declared in `ConfigureServices`, then you'll still get a null exception on that `Resolve` line. In that case, find on [VS Call Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window) the line that shows what "service" is asked for.

`ConfigureServices` will need another `services.AddHttpClient<ISomeService, ...` for that service. (replace `ISomeService` with whatever Interface defines that service.)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you should initialize service provider before register SignUpViewModel because the Resolve method use serviceProvider inside itself . Probably you are using Resolve method in your code . Need to check your code

Comment: github.com/techwithpat/XamWebApiClient I followed this example.

Comment: Could you share App.xaml.cs and AppShell.xaml.cs with us ?